# How to delete a specific value based on the column before in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that has a list of variables. However, I have printed the last two columns which I am interested in. I want to delete all occurrences of **NAs** in  the **value** column only when b**s_Scores == bs_24.**

```
bs_Scores   value
bs_0    16.7
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   33.3
bs_24   NA
bs_0    25
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   NA
bs_24   0
bs_0    16.7
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   16.7
bs_24   16.7
bs_0    NA
```

Essentially, I want to delete all the rows within bs_24 that have an NA in the value column while preserving all the NAs in bs_0, bs_1 and bs_12.

SO it should look like this

```
bs_Scores   value
bs_0    16.7
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   33.3
bs_0    25
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   NA
bs_24   0
bs_0    16.7
bs_1    41.7
bs_12   16.7
bs_24   16.7
bs_0    NA
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the expected output is correct, I am not sure what is the issue in the solution I posted

Comment: Sorry my fault. I just realised I don't have NAs but blanks (no data). So I am not sure how to get rid of the bs_24 = blanks

Comment: bs_24 is a value in 'bs_Scores'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base R` with `subset`

```
subset(df1, !((is.na(value) & bs_Scores == 'bs_24')|bs_Scores == ""))
```

-output

```
 bs_Scores value
1       bs_0  16.7
2       bs_1  41.7
3      bs_12  33.3
5       bs_0  25.0
6       bs_1  41.7
7      bs_12    NA
8      bs_24   0.0
9       bs_0  16.7
10      bs_1  41.7
11     bs_12  16.7
12     bs_24  16.7
13      bs_0    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(bs_Scores = c("bs_0", "bs_1", "bs_12", "bs_24", 
"bs_0", "bs_1", "bs_12", "bs_24", "bs_0", "bs_1", "bs_12", "bs_24", 
"bs_0"), value = c(16.7, 41.7, 33.3, NA, 25, 41.7, NA, 0, 16.7, 
41.7, 16.7, 16.7, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I noticed that bs_24 is missing. I only want the bs_24 
 = NA to be missing but not other values.

Comment: @HKJ3 I looked at your expected and it looks exxactly like the solution posted

Comment: @HKJ3 in my answer, `bs_12    NA` is not deleted

Comment: You are right. It is my fault. I just noticed I have blanks rather than NA. How would I filter out blanks.

Comment: @HKJ3 you said earlier that you don't want to delete NA for other cases?

Comment: Sorry, I am awful at explaining. I have realised rather than having NAs I have blank data for some bs_24 in the value column. Which is why the is.na function was not working for me. Is there a way to get rid  of bs_24 that is specifically equal to  the  blanks?

Comment: @HKJ3 try the update `subset(df1, !((is.na(value) & bs_Scores == 'bs_24')|bs_Scores == ""))`

Answer (score 2):

with subset using `dplyr`
you can use the code below

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% subset(!is.na(value) & bs_Scores != "bs_24" )
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bs_scores <- tibble::tribble(
               ~bs_Scores, ~value,
                   "bs_0",   16.7,
                   "bs_1",   41.7,
                  "bs_12",   33.3,
                  "bs_24",     NA,
                   "bs_0",     25,
                   "bs_1",   41.7,
                  "bs_12",     NA,
                  "bs_24",      0,
                   "bs_0",   16.7,
                   "bs_1",   41.7,
                  "bs_12",   16.7,
                  "bs_24",   16.7,
                   "bs_0",     NA
               )
bs_scores %>% 
  filter(!(bs_Scores == "bs_24" & (is.na(value))))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 2
#>    bs_Scores value
#>    <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 bs_0       16.7
#>  2 bs_1       41.7
#>  3 bs_12      33.3
#>  4 bs_0       25  
#>  5 bs_1       41.7
#>  6 bs_12      NA  
#>  7 bs_24       0  
#>  8 bs_0       16.7
#>  9 bs_1       41.7
#> 10 bs_12      16.7
#> 11 bs_24      16.7
#> 12 bs_0       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>